# Damaged luggage compansation -Air China

Tags: compensation, damaged-luggage, air-china

My suitcase was delayed at Dalian Airport (China), I went to the Air China customer center and filled out the form at the airport "confirmation of passenger baggage information". They told me I will receive my suitcase at the hotel in the next 24hours, and in fact it was. So, I received it the next day and realized that it was damaged.
I sent an email to the Air China department at the airport of Dalian asking for compensation for the delay and for the damaged suitcase, I have called 15 times and so far, two months later I still have not received any response. I called to the European customer service, and they said I have to wait from a reply.

Does anyone know what else I can do?

Comment: What was the itinerary? This will determine what rules are applicable, especially if the Montreal Convention applies. Did you incur any costs due to the delay (buying toiletries, clothes…)? Did you keep the relevant receipts/invoices?

Comment: That happened  to me on United and I got screwed. For United you MUST file a damaged luggage claim at the airport presenting the damaged bag. Since the bag was lost and delivered, I would have had to go back to the airport which would have been very time consuming and expensive. Ironically I saw (and photographed) the bag in it's damaged state twice along the way (in Jakarta and SFO) but no one would accept a claim. You insisted I file at the final destination.

Comment: Hi Hilmar, My itinerary was Vienna-Frankfurt-Peking-Dalian. How do I know if the Montreal convention applies? I didn't go to the airport because I received my suitcase at the hotel and as you said it would have been very time consuming for me. So I just sent an email with the pictures of the damaged suitcase and also the relevant invoices. But I didn't received any feedback and when I call to the airline they just say that I have to wait untill the airport replies and give me a feedback but I think it won't happen :(